# Replace escaped quotes

Tags: apex, string, escape, replace

I want to replace all escaped quotes, but leave default quotes. How can  i do it?

```
string s1 = '"five1,five2", six ,seven,"eig\"ht1,eight2","nine",,eleven';

String lst = s1.replace('\\"','$');
System.debug(lst);
```

Comment: There are unescape methods are present on string class. Use those example - s1.unescapeJava(), s1.unescapeUnicode();

Comment: @YsrShk it just make them unescaped, but i need to replace them with another symbol.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
string s1 = '"five1,five2", six ,seven,"eig\\"ht1,eight2","nine",,eleven';

String lst = s1.replaceAll('\\\\"','\\$');
System.debug(lst);
```

See e.g. [Can't escape the backslash with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025482/cant-escape-the-backslash-with-regex) for some detail on needing multiple levels of escaping.

But the quick explanation is that for a backslash to be treated literally by the Apex compiler it needs to be escaped itself by a backslash, and then another layer of escaping is needed for regex engine too. Hence 2 * 2 = 4 backslashes needed.

And `$` has special meaning in regex too, so that character needs escaping.

Comment: Nice, thank you!